# jquery $.post doesnt sent post data

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, post

im trying to make a post request to the server but the jquery doesnt sent any post date.

i already tried to use: (suggestions i found on the web)

```
var postdata = {'username':username,'password':password,'src':'web'};
```

instead of

```
var postdata = 'username=' + username + '&pass=' + password + '&src=web';
```

this is my jquery code:

```
var username = $('#uForm_un').val();
var password = $('#uForm_pw').val();
var postdata = 'username=' + username + '&pass=' + password + '&src=web';
console.log(postdata);//output: username=administrator&pass=password&src=web 
$.post(
    "inc/api/do.login.ajax",
    postdata,
    function (data) {
        console.log(data);//output: a vardump($_POST) wich is empty.
    }
);
```

browser data:

```
Remote Address:62.***.**.**:80
Request URL:***********/inc/api/do.login.ajax/
Request Method:GET
Status Code:200 OK
Request Headersview source
Accept:*/*
Accept-Encoding:gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language:nl-NL,nl;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4
Cache-Control:no-cache
Connection:keep-alive
Cookie:anonymous=-81523622186; windowtop=100; LanguageId=1; CurrencyId=1; space_history=%7B%221%22%3A%2220%22%7D; eventId=1; OrderId=201424754035; filter_starttime=6%3A00; filter_endtime=12%3A00; _ga=GA1.2.2031844175.1410181977; __atuvc=13%7C37; PHPSESSID=4x1xc4ca4238a0b923820dcc509a6f75849b; filter_display_mode=grid; filter_search=; filter_where=eindhoven; filter_startdate=01/09/2014; filter_enddate=05/09/2014; filter_order=itemdate; filter_dayparts=; filter_distance=100000; filter_categories=; list=%2C2797
Host:********.nl
Pragma:no-cache
Referer:***************/index.php?action=editvisit
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/37.0.2062.103 Safari/537.36
X-Requested-With:XMLHttpRequest
Response Headersview source
Connection:Keep-Alive
Content-Encoding:gzip
Content-Length:156
Content-Type:text/html; charset=utf-8
Date:Thu, 11 Sep 2014 09:15:03 GMT
Keep-Alive:timeout=5, max=88
Server:Apache/2.2.22 (Debian)
Vary:Accept-Encoding
X-Powered-By:PHP/5.4.4-14+deb7u14
```

EDIT:

now i use this code, but with the same result...

```
$.post( "inc/api/do.login.ajax",{ 
                username : ""+$('#uForm_un').val()+"", 
                pass     : ""+$('#uForm_pw').val()+"",
                src      : "web"
            }).done(function(data) { 
               console.log(data);
            }, "json" );
```

Comment: I diddnt downvote your answers! i cant downvote them havent got 150 rep...

Comment: How about using web debugger like Fiddler or Wireshark to investigate what is going on? http://www.telerik.com/download/fiddler, https://www.wireshark.org/

Answer (score 0):

Solution:

change this:
inc/api/do.login.ajax

to

inc/api/do.login.ajax/index.php

with a get request it works fine but with a post...

sorry for taking your time and thanks! every answer was usefull!